# Address changes upon transferring Eigen array from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I make a c++ function to create numpy arrays with the correct memory alignment.

Somehow, python and c++ print two different addresses for the "same" array.

Does that means pybind11 still copy the array?

If that is the case, how to avoid copying?

The pybind11 is from: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/archive/stable.zip

c++ code:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>

template <typename T>
inline Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>* eigen_empty(Index rows, Index cols) {
    auto a = new Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>(rows, cols);
    std::cout << "Address: " << (long long) a << "\n";
    return a;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(_cxx, m) {
    m.def("eigen_empty_d", &eigen_empty<double>,
          py::return_value_policy::take_ownership);
}  // python would "take_ownership" of the array
```

python test:

```
>>> x=eigen_empty_d(10,1);x.__array_interface__['data'][0];x.flags.owndata
Address: 32962272  # address printed by c++
29726560           # address from python
False              # numpy does not own the data
>>> x=eigen_empty_d(10,1);x.__array_interface__['data'][0];x.flags.owndata
Address: 32962240
29511904
False
>>> x=eigen_empty_d(10,1);x.__array_interface__['data'][0];x.flags.owndata
Address: 29516656
29726560
False
>>> x=eigen_empty_d(10,1);x.__array_interface__['data'][0];x.flags.owndata
Address: 33209440
29726560
False
>>> x=eigen_empty_d(10,1);x.__array_interface__['data'][0];x.flags.owndata
Address: 29429712
29511904
False
```

Comment: The addresses are different because they point to different objects of different *types*. On tge Python side you have the data (the actual array of numbers) and on the C++ side you have the Eigen Array object.

Comment: But sometimes the c++ number is bigger than python. Sometimes it is smaller. It is not just a constant shift.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Should print `(*a).data()` from eigen array.

Comment: now they match. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the C++ line printing the address to this:

```
std::cout << "Address: " << (long long) a->data() << "\n";
```

Now it's printing the actual address of the array in memory. Without referring to the `data()` method you're just printing the address of the Eigen wrapper object of the actual array.

Comment: I still don't get the `x.flags.owndata`. I thought pybind11 would do that for me.